# Java JMenuBar Rollover Issue

Tags: java, macos, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

So for some reason, sometimes the rollover selection will wig out when moving from one menu item to another quickly like so:

[image: Like this]
[image: Or this]

I'm only using all of the defaults, is this a java bug? Or did I do something wrong?
Here is some compilable code that acts in this way:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


public class example {
    static JFrame frame;
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("~Module Logger~");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550,325));

        //Add Menu Bar Components
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file, pointTo, helpBar, moduleCommands;
        file = new JMenu("File");
        moduleCommands = new JMenu("Module Commands");
        JMenuItem about,clearAutocomplete, help, pointToTest, pointToLive, reset;
        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        clearAutocomplete = new JMenuItem("Clear Autocomplete Data");
        pointTo = new JMenu("Point to Server...");
        helpBar = new JMenu("Help");
        pointToTest = new JMenuItem("Test Server");
        pointToLive = new JMenuItem("Live Server");
        reset = new JMenuItem("Reset Module");
        help = new JMenuItem("Help Menu");
        pointTo.add(pointToTest);
        pointTo.add( Box.createVerticalStrut( 3 ) );
        pointTo.add(pointToLive);
        file.add(clearAutocomplete);
        file.add( Box.createVerticalStrut( 3 ) );
        file.add(about);
        moduleCommands.add(reset);
        moduleCommands.add( Box.createVerticalStrut( 3 ) );
        moduleCommands.add(pointTo);
        helpBar.add(help);
        menuBar.add(file);
        menuBar.add(moduleCommands);
        menuBar.add(helpBar);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);       

        //Set up the content pane.
        //addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted does not compile so we can't tell if we get the same results or not. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What version of MacOS and Java are you using?  Also, I wouldn't mess with the preferred size of the frame, as this will need to include the frame decorations in your calculations, better to rely on the content to provide sizing hints

Comment: I don't have a Mac so I can't reproduce the issue, but as far as I can see you're not doing anything weird, so I can only conclude it is a bug, which you should report (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/).

Comment: I'm using version MacOS 10.9.4 and just updated to Java 7u67 and I'm still recreating the issue.